# is it possible to use "use strict"; conditionally, when say you are in development environment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

( all examples from chrome ) 
This does not work:

```
if (InDevEnvironment) {
    "use strict";
    undeclaredVar = 1;
}
undeclaredVar2 = 1;
```

ie, strict mode is not applies, and both undeclared variables are not set as global

However this works :

```
"use strict";
undeclaredVar = 1;
undeclaredVar2 = 1;
```

ie, strict mode is applied and both lines will generate an error

QUESTION - is there a way to apply strict mode, depending on some conditional JavaScript statement?

Comment: why not keep it on? you will produce better code

Comment: @DanielA.White because keeping it on, may produce erorrs, in place of working code. 

so if you are trying to start applying strict mode to a multi thousand line project, you want to do it carefully

Comment: they recommend wrapping it up in a function and executing that function instead of having it at the toplevel.

Comment: @GregBala: If you write modular code you can restrict the `"use strict"` directives to modules.

Comment: I know @FelixKling. but I would like to apply it to existing, large modules, that I cannot fully test before releasing. at least in dev, I can slowly fix issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to apply strict mode, depending on some conditional JavaScript statement

Not *reasonably*, no. There are a few *unreasonable* ways to do it (off the top of my head: using ajax to load your script and adding/not adding `"use strict";` at the top before putting it in a `script` element and adding the element to the page).

But I wouldn't if you can avoid it. There's no particularly good reason to remove it, just leave it there. If the code has cleared development and testing with it in place, having it in place in production shouldn't be an issue and may well give you important, time-saving information if a bug slips past development and testing. (Client to customer support: "It's broken" Support to client: "Press F12 and click Console, do you see anything in red?" Client to support: "It says `ReferenceError`..." -- result!)

---

Your question specifically asked about using a JavaScript variable to do it, but you can do this *not* with a JavaScript variable quite easily. For instance, you can use a script minifier/combiner to do it:

`"use strict"` works a function- and code-compilation unit level, and the `"use strict"` must be the [**first** non-comment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14.1) in the unit. So this is strict code:

```
"use strict";
doSomethingCool();
```

this is *not* strict code:

```
doSomethingCool();
"use strict";
/* This would not be strict code here */
```

The `"use strict"` in the second example is just a dead expression, it has no effect.

So in your modules, as you migrate them to strict mode, you can add `"use strict";` to the tops of the modules, but then have your script combiner add something *in front* of that when combining and minifying. That has the effect of disabling the statement. Since you presumably don't use the script combiner/minifier (instead loading the modules directly), strict mode would be enabled in dev but not production.